# Custom marker with Angular Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using the Angular Google maps directive to show maps on my webpage.  Currently my markers are created using SVG but this is slow as I have to pass my information into a function that creates an SVG in memory to pass to the Google Icon. So I want to replace it with a custom HTML marker which will hopefully be less code and can leverage CSS classes for lots of the heavy lifting.

Unfortunately this isn't available as standard within the Angular Google Maps markers (unless I havent seen it?!)

I found a [tutorial](http://humaan.com/custom-html-markers-google-maps/) on how to do this with Overlays but I need clustering to work with my icons.

How can I do this? Without rewriting everything from scratch? Ideally I'd like to leverage as much of the existing angular-google-maps code as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up doing this was to put in rich HTML into the `labelContent` property, setting a class on it via `labelClass` and then setting the `icon` to be transparent (https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png)

This way the actual icon is invisible but you can create rich HTML / CSS markers through the label.  And this doesnt break functionality with the clusterer

Comment: I've the same issue, do you mind sharing an example?